# Trouble parsing data JSON alamofire SwiftJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, xcode8

Trying to parse a sample JSON object using alamofire and SwiftlyJSON from http been having trouble to parse it to my product model. It's really strange, I ran the debugger within the for loops, I iterate over and do a "po self.productlist", the value was indeed appended into the array. But when I try to print it outside the loop, then it wasn't working, same thing when I try to do "po self.productlist[0]["product"]" in debugger mode. It's really strange at one point it was working. As you can see I've attached 2 image below in the imgur links.

I've also attach my controller and model, I'm not sure what mistake I done, or maybe there is a bug. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Controller

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class AddProductController: UITableViewController {
    var productlist = [Product]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1f1zop").responseJSON { response in
            let jsondata = JSON(data: response.data!)
            for index in 0..<jsondata["data"].count{

                self.productlist.append(Product(id: jsondata["data"][index]["id"].stringValue, product: jsondata["data"][index]["product"].stringValue, category: jsondata["data"][index]["category"].stringValue, price: jsondata["data"][index]["price"].doubleValue))
            }
        }
        print(self.productlist[0]["id"])
```

Model

```
import Foundation

class Product {
    var id:String
    var product:String
    var category: String
    var price: Double


    init(id:String, product:String, category:String, price:Double) {
        self.id = id
        self.product = product
        self.category = category
        self.price = price
    }    
}
```

[image: Controller shown with Product List[1]]

[image: Debugger shown variable productlist was indeed append with value]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw4K4.png)

**Update to vadian**
Thanks i got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No bug, that's the famous *async-trap*.

Alamofire request works asynchronously, the JSON is returned **after** the `print` line.

Just put the `print` line – and also the code to process the array – into the completion block.

The error occurs, because you try to get `id` like a dictionary. Use the property `.id`

By the way: Please don't use index based loops in Swift

```
    Alamofire.request("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1f1zop").responseJSON { response in
        let jsondata = JSON(data: response.data!)
        for product in jsondata["data"].array! {
            self.productlist.append(Product(id: product["id"].stringValue, product: product["product"].stringValue, category: product["category"].stringValue, price: product["price"].doubleValue))
        }
        print(self.productlist[0].id) // use the property, it's not a dictionary.
    }
```

**Note**: If the JSON is loaded from a third party service you should use optional bindings to parse the data safely.

Comment: ah i actually did tried the for loops like what u did but i can't get it to work, probably missed out the ".array!"

Also, thanks it is able to print now. But my main objective is to get the data out of alamofire codeblock, so i can transfer the data to other place like for instance tableview data source etc. Does that mean i can only limit within that codeblock? Sorry if it sound kinda noob, i'm very new to ios programming, any work around or suggestion to get these data out of here.

Comment: Think asynchronously. Just write the code you want to execute outside the block inside the block for example assign the array to a data source array and reload the table view. But consider to dispatch code affecting the UI on the main thread.